# Decimal Trimmed after 2 digits added Zeros while store to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, decimal

I trying to store the Latitude and Longitude to my database.

I have these columns in my table:

```
[Latitude]  NUMERIC(12, 8) NULL,
[Longitude] NUMERIC(12, 8) NULL,
```

In the C# model class, my properties are:

```
[Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
[Range(-9999.99999999, 9999.99999999)]
public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
[Range(-9999.99999999, 9999.99999999)]
public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
```

I want to store these `Latitude` and `Longitude` values into my database table.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help

```
decimal lats = decimal.Parse("56.12345678");
decimal longs = decimal.Parse("10.18732210");

context.test.Add(new test
        {
            Latitude = lats,
            Longitude = longs
        });
context.SaveChanges();
```

It stores the values in the database table like this:

```
Latitude: 56.12000000  
Longitude : 10.18000000
```

I want the same value to be stored in the database:

```
"56.12345678"     
"10.18732210"
```

Comment: Try adding the precision to the `TypeName`. e.g. `numeric(12,8)`

Comment: I already have this Type in Sql for this Columns

Comment: Are you using EF Core?

Comment: Your c# also needs to be aware of the precision. You can use the Fluent API approach as provided in the answer below, but since you are already using the data annotations to provide the type I would specify it in there by adding the precision into the `TypeName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to specify it also in your OnModelCreating like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(a => a.Latitude).HasPrecision(18, 9);
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(a => a.Longitude).HasPrecision(18, 9);
```

Just in case you need more advanced features and you are using EF Core take a look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Comment: Also it could be useful to take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.spatial.dbgeography?view=netframework-4.8 just in case you need more advanced features